# missing file in building corona sdk?

Tags: file, lua, mp3, coronasdk

I am developing a project that uses `mp3` and `.lrc` file for my game in corona sdk.
when i try to build it on android and run it on the android device, i got this error..

```
Director ERROR: Failed to execute new(params) function on 'gameLoad'.
```

so i wonder that there is missing file in my game.

it is possible that the `mp3` and `.lrc` files didn't build together with the game code?

can anyone can give idea about my case? thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of director are you using?   The latest version of director class (1.4 I think) prints THE ACTUAL ERROR that causes the problem.

The error which you have mentioned is just the error in director class which you have no control over. You will get something like this.

```
-----------------------
Director ERROR: Failed to execute new( params ) function on 'mainscreen'.
-----------------------
e:\corona\satheesh\doodle2\mainscreen.lua:35: attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'screen' (a nil value)
Runtime error
```

**EDIT**

If you need these messages to be show on device, do the following changes to director.lua

1.set

```
showDebug = true
```

2.Change

```
local alert = native.showAlert( "Director Class - ERROR", message, { "OK" }, onComplete )
```

to

```
local alert = native.showAlert( "Director Class - ERROR",debugMessage, { "OK" }, onComplete )
```

Comment: thanks SatheeshJM for your answer, i am using `Version: 1.4`, in my simulator, it works fine but in the device, i got those error... btw, is there a way i can view the error in the device?